# Сравнивание списков в Pythom

Tags: python, функции

У меня есть код:

```
def compare_lists(lst, lst2):
    itms = 0
    for i, j in zip(lst, lst2):
        if i == j:
            itms += 1
    return itms
```

и он сравнивает списки, выводя количество элементов которые в них совпадают. Можно использовать что-то по типу `lst.compare(lst2)` вмество этой функции?

Comment: нет, нельзя....

Comment: itms = sum([1 for i, j in zip(lst, lst2) if i == j])

Answer (score 2):

Используйте пересечение множеств

```
lst1 =[1,2,3,4,5]
lst2 =[2,3,4,5,6]
print(len(set(lst1).intersection(lst2)))
```

```
4
```

Comment: у меня просто есть повторяющиеся элементы, не подходит

Comment: @Anikei жаль, что вы не написали об этом в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Или вы хотите вызывать функцию так **lst1.compare(lst2)**, а не так **compare(lst1, lst2)** тогда вам нужно создать класс для **lst** по тому что в данном примере вы продемонстрировали вызов метода класса